# Regex - catching remaining pages of a subfoler

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

For Google Analytics, I'm trying to separate the subfolders of a subfolder: I don't know how to add a line that matches all pages of the subfolder not currently matched.

E.g.:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/$") THEN "home"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/tomato/.*") THEN "tomato"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/plum/.*") THEN "plum"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/grape/.*") THEN "grape"
ELSE "Others"
END
```

What line do I need to add for an "Other UK pages" match?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the path `.*/uk/.*` would cover this edge case:

```
CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/$") THEN "home"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/tomato/.*") THEN "tomato"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/plum/.*") THEN "plum"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/grape/.*") THEN "grape"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/.*") THEN "Other UK pages"
    ELSE "Others"
END
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still matches all pages within the subfolders. Not sure if there's a way to exclude otherwise matched pages. I've tried the following but doesn't work either:
 `WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/.*")
        AND REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/tomato/.*")=FALSE

        AND REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/plum/.*")=FALSE

        AND REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,".*/uk/grape/.*")=FALSE 
THEN "Other UK pages"`